# Using console.log for debugging with Classic ASP

Tags: debugging, asp-classic, while-loop, console.log

I am looking at an a webpage written in classic ASP and I am in the middle of a 'while' statement. I want to use the Chrome Developer tools to debug the values on my page. I tried inserting

```
console.log(value);
```

which works with C# applications, but it threw a `Expected end of statement` at the `console.log` line I inserted.

I am just looking for a quick tip on how use the debugger with classic asp?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would need to Response.Write a script block with the console.log statement. Assuming the ASP page outputs html.

Comment: I quite frequently use Response.End after the Response.Write

Answer (score 26):

I make it by a function that returns a javascript console.log() and it works fine for me in the most used browsers (IE 10, Chrome, FireFox).

```
function aspLog(value)
    response.Write("<script language=javascript>console.log(`'" & value & "'`); </script>")
end function
```

Then, just call it in the asp page (or functions.asp file):

```
aspLog("Test text")
aspLog(100.0)
```

Unfortunately, this makes the html generated is full of javascript tags. So do not forget to comment or remove theses calls to the function aspLog() when the code is ready .
If you use backticks `` you can handle inputs with both single and double quotes. Like sql queries etc.